# Debian Jessie broken dependencies: The following packages have been kept back: librtmp1

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I seldom mess around with my productive debian 8 system, so I can't remember when or how this problem was introduced. I noticed it when trying to install `openshot` and got unmet dependencies (output at the end, because my problem seems to go deeper).

I did `apt-get update` and it works as usual, no warnings or errors. But `apt-get upgrade` reports:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  librtmp1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Why kept back? Trying `apt-get install librtmp1`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 librtmp1 : Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.5.6) but it is not installable
            Depends: libhogweed4 but it is not installable
            Depends: libnettle6 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

"Not installable" sounds nasty. But I can't remove it, because among the packages that depend on it (directly or indirecly) are basics as cmake, libre-office and kde-runtime (and blender, gimp, qemu and many others).

some postings suggest to do `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but that does nothing:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

One more strange observation on my manual fixing attempts doing `apt-get install python-mlt` it comes to very basic conflicts for libstdc++6:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-mlt : Depends: libmlt++3 (>= 1:6.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmlt6 (>= 1:6.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5) but 4.9.2-10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Update: `/etc/apt/sources.list`:**

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb-src http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org testing main non-free
```

I don't remember when that multimedia testing got into it ...

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy python-mlt libmlt++3 libmlt6 libstdc++6`? And similarly `apt-cache policy librtmp1 libgnutls30 libhogweed4 libnettle6` . Paste into the question, not as a comment. This output usually gives useful information about what is going on. And you probably want to avoid using "www.deb-multimedia.org", unless you have it pinned to a low priority and know what you are doing.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thank you. Good hint, but as you can see, my problem was already solved. Indeed the problem was the sources and I had forgot what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `sources.list` , replace `testing` by `jessie` then run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
pt-get install python-mlt
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.